# Function CSV to EXCEL in Python

Tags: python, pandas, function, path

I want to transform a csv document into excel.
I also want it to be a function which uses the document's path.
I know that I have to use the code below but that's not a function.
Please help me if you can.

Comment: I think you missed the "use the code below" part when posting the question.  You can edit your question above to add it.  You may want to expand on what you mean by function (expected outcome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand without any code in the question (for now), I think this should work:

```py
def csv_to_excel(source_path, source_file, target_path, target_file):
    """ Take the path of a csv file, convert it to excel and save it"""
    import pandas as pd
    import os
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(source_path, source_file))
        df.to_excel(os.path.join(target_path, target_file), index=False)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
```

The imports can (and should generally) be made in the main scope. Please leave a comment if there is something you do not understand.

Comment: The code you wrote was helpfull but i want to make a function that can transport a file on a different path make it into excell and then zip the file i think it would be way better if it as like def _name_ (sourse path, source file name, destination path, destination file name):

Comment: @ΧρήστοςΓουμενίδης I just updated the code to match your requirements. Glad to hear it was helpful. :)